# Make Sharepoint online list title clickable

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list in my Sharepoint online, which looks like this:[image: sharepoint list]

I would like to make the title "**phone**" clickable. Is it somehow possible with **JSON formatting**? Or what is the best way to make it clickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json formatting can only change the format of the list column values, the list title will not be editable via JSON. You may need to use 3rd party web parts like modern script editor as the modern pages for now only support limited customization.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it, with [SPFX Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension).

What it will do is, inject a script, could be native javascript or jQuery to the page via the spfx application customizer.

The script that you will inject will be the 1 to make the list title clickable, you can modify the element to actually what ever you want, a link, a button, a div, etc.

Hope the concept helps, Happy Coding!